# Laravel Integer Validation without quotes

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

Using Laravel 8, in a JSON POST request I have a field `{ "is_active": "1"}` in string quotes.  Have the below validation in Laravel

```
'is_active' => ['required','integer',Rule::in([0, 1]) ]
```

It's accepting integer 1 even enclosed in quotes. How to do strict check so that it allows only `{ "is_active": 1}`

Comment: Maybe validate as bool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type **casting converts the value to a chosen type by writing the type within parentheses before the value to convert.** The casts allowed are: (int) - cast to int.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#cast-parameters

e.g

We have a property of a model called **cast** in which you can specify your column names just like below:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'rating' => 'integer',
];
```

Comment: instead of casting we can create custom validation rule and use is_string function to verify whether request is string

Comment: **CAUTION:** The answer is wrong, since the question was about an incoming request, so there's no model involved (yet)

Answer (score 0):

To check data type duration validation, use this package:

https://github.com/qtlenh/laravel-strict-validator

add `strict` into your validation rules:

```
'is_active' => ['integer:strict',...]
```